# Android studio and chrome sound sluggish performance

Tags: windows, google-chrome, android-studio

I code in android studio without emulator. I have 6gb ram. Athlon 2x 6000. Windows 8.1 64bit. Sometimes I have a music mix playing on chrome at the background. Whenever I do an action in android studio the music may pause briefly for some seconds depending on the heaviness of the task. If I build... ok then the music might pause for longer than that. *I once found somewhere on the net it might be related to java 64 bit.* I was using ubuntu 14.04 and it went so smoothly... But now I have windows 8.1 . Is there any solution without changing OS or hardware?

Answer (score 0):

If you face my problem you can install jdk 32bit.